# Analysing crash report from Test Flight - React Native App

Tags: ios, react-native, testflight

I've published a React Native App and released it through TestFlight to some internal users of the company.
While on debug and testing before the release we've never had reported crashes, some users started experiencing random crashes on the App (at restart, the App continued as normal).
Now, since the app is developed in React Native, the crash log reported from TestFlight doesn't seem to be so useful, at least for me, at tracking down the possible bug.

This is the crash log:

```
Exception Type:  EXC_CRASH (SIGABRT)
Exception Codes: 0x0000000000000000, 0x0000000000000000
Exception Note:  EXC_CORPSE_NOTIFY
Triggered by Thread:  10

Last Exception Backtrace:
0   CoreFoundation                  0x1a3d6aa48 __exceptionPreprocess + 220 (NSException.m:199)
1   libobjc.A.dylib                 0x1a3a91fa4 objc_exception_throw + 56 (objc-exception.mm:565)
2   *App Name*              0x100ab475c RCTFatal + 668 (RCTAssert.m:146)
3   *App Name*              0x100b2528c -[RCTExceptionsManager reportFatalException:stack:exceptionId:] + 496 (RCTExceptionsManager.mm:65)
4   CoreFoundation                  0x1a3d70c20 __invoking___ + 144
5   CoreFoundation                  0x1a3c40d30 -[NSInvocation invoke] + 300 (NSForwarding.m:3306)
6   CoreFoundation                  0x1a3c41908 -[NSInvocation invokeWithTarget:] + 76 (NSForwarding.m:3412)
7   *App Name*              0x100ae67dc -[RCTModuleMethod invokeWithBridge:module:arguments:] + 460 (RCTModuleMethod.mm:569)
8   *App Name*              0x100ae88c8 facebook::react::invokeInner(RCTBridge*, RCTModuleData*, unsigned int, folly::dynamic const&) + 244 (RCTNativeModule.mm:108)
9   *App Name*              0x100ae862c invocation function for block in facebook::react::RCTNativeModule::invoke(unsigned int, folly::dynamic&&, int) + 88 (RCTNativeModule.mm:73)
10  libdispatch.dylib               0x1a3a36610 _dispatch_call_block_and_release + 24 (init.c:1408)
11  libdispatch.dylib               0x1a3a37184 _dispatch_client_callout + 16 (object.m:495)
12  libdispatch.dylib               0x1a39e3404 _dispatch_lane_serial_drain$VARIANT$mp + 608 (inline_internal.h:2484)
13  libdispatch.dylib               0x1a39e3df8 _dispatch_lane_invoke$VARIANT$mp + 420 (queue.c:3863)
14  libdispatch.dylib               0x1a39ed314 _dispatch_workloop_worker_thread + 588 (queue.c:6445)
15  libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x1a3a86b88 _pthread_wqthread + 276 (pthread.c:2351)
16  libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x1a3a89760 start_wqthread + 8

Thread 0 name:
Thread 0:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00000001a3b40634 mach_msg_trap + 8
1   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00000001a3b3faa0 mach_msg + 72 (mach_msg.c:103)
2   CoreFoundation                  0x00000001a3ce8288 __CFRunLoopServiceMachPort + 216 (CFRunLoop.c:2575)
3   CoreFoundation                  0x00000001a3ce33a8 __CFRunLoopRun + 1444 (CFRunLoop.c:2931)
4   CoreFoundation                  0x00000001a3ce2adc CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 464 (CFRunLoop.c:3192)
5   GraphicsServices                0x00000001adc83328 GSEventRunModal + 104 (GSEvent.c:2246)
6   UIKitCore                       0x00000001a7df063c UIApplicationMain + 1936 (UIApplication.m:4773)
7   *App Name*              0x0000000100a53078 main + 88 (main.m:14)
8   libdyld.dylib                   0x00000001a3b6c360 start + 4

Thread 1 name:
Thread 1:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00000001a3b40634 mach_msg_trap + 8
1   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00000001a3b3faa0 mach_msg + 72 (mach_msg.c:103)
2   CoreFoundation                  0x00000001a3ce8288 __CFRunLoopServiceMachPort + 216 (CFRunLoop.c:2575)
3   CoreFoundation                  0x00000001a3ce33a8 __CFRunLoopRun + 1444 (CFRunLoop.c:2931)
4   CoreFoundation                  0x00000001a3ce2adc CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 464 (CFRunLoop.c:3192)
5   Foundation                      0x00000001a4022784 -[NSRunLoop(NSRunLoop) runMode:beforeDate:] + 228 (NSRunLoop.m:374)
6   Foundation                      0x00000001a4022664 -[NSRunLoop(NSRunLoop) runUntilDate:] + 88 (NSRunLoop.m:421)
7   UIKitCore                       0x00000001a7e88e80 -[UIEventFetcher threadMain] + 152 (UIEventFetcher.m:637)
8   Foundation                      0x00000001a415309c __NSThread__start__ + 848 (NSThread.m:724)
9   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00000001a3a85d8c _pthread_start + 156 (pthread.c:896)
10  libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00000001a3a8976c thread_start + 8

Thread 2 name:
Thread 2:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00000001a3b61c94 __psynch_cvwait + 8
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00000001a3a7ecf8 _pthread_cond_wait$VARIANT$mp + 680 (pthread_cond.c:591)
2   libc++.1.dylib                  0x00000001a3bb47a8 std::__1::condition_variable::wait(std::__1::unique_lock<std::__1::mutex>&) + 24 (__threading_support:287)
3   JavaScriptCore                  0x00000001b2b0538c void std::__1::condition_variable_any::wait<std::__1::unique_lock<bmalloc::Mutex> >(std::__1::uni... + 108 (condition_variable:204)
4   JavaScriptCore                  0x00000001b2b03dfc bmalloc::Heap::tryAllocateLarge(std::__1::unique_lock<bmalloc::Mutex>&, unsigned long, unsigned l... + 236 (condition_variable:213)
5   JavaScriptCore                  0x00000001b2afdb14 bmalloc::Allocator::tryAllocate(unsigned long) + 196 (Allocator.cpp:59)
6   JavaScriptCore                  0x00000001b2a96d1c WTF::tryFastMalloc(unsigned long) + 48 (Cache.h:74)
7   JavaScriptCore                  0x00000001b2ab5fc4 WTF::StringBuilder::allocateBufferUpConvert(unsigned char const*, unsigned int) + 84 (StringImpl.h:979)
8   JavaScriptCore                  0x00000001b2ab7454 WTF::StringBuilder::appendQuotedJSONString(WTF::String const&) + 224 (StringBuilderJSON.cpp:128)
9   JavaScriptCore                  0x00000001b34b9094 JSC::Stringifier::appendStringifiedValue(WTF::StringBuilder&, JSC::JSValue, JSC::Stringifier::Hol... + 3872 (JSONObject.cpp:368)
10  JavaScriptCore                  0x00000001b34bb1ec JSC::Stringifier::Holder::appendNextProperty(JSC::Stringifier&, WTF::StringBuilder&) + 6744 (JSONObject.cpp:574)
11  JavaScriptCore                  0x00000001b34b93e4 JSC::Stringifier::appendStringifiedValue(WTF::StringBuilder&, JSC::JSValue, JSC::Stringifier::Hol... + 4720 (JSONObject.cpp:421)
12  JavaScriptCore                  0x00000001b34b7f98 JSC::Stringifier::stringify(JSC::JSValue) + 268 (JSONObject.cpp:282)
13  JavaScriptCore                  0x00000001b34bd33c JSC::JSONProtoFuncStringify(JSC::ExecState*) + 144 (JSONObject.cpp:848)
14  JavaScriptCore                  0x00000001b2cbd9cc llint_entry + 135068
15  JavaScriptCore                  0x00000001b2cbb080 llint_entry + 124496
16  JavaScriptCore                  0x00000001b2cbb128 llint_entry + 124664
17  JavaScriptCore                  0x00000001b2cbb080 llint_entry + 124496
18  JavaScriptCore                  0x00000001b2cbc56c llint_entry + 129852
19  JavaScriptCore                  0x00000001b2cbb080 llint_entry + 124496
20  JavaScriptCore                  0x00000001b2cbb128 llint_entry + 124664
21  JavaScriptCore                  0x00000001b2cbb080 llint_entry + 124496
22  JavaScriptCore                  0x00000001b2c9c7e8 vmEntryToJavaScript + 248
23  JavaScriptCore                  0x00000001b31faea4 JSC::Interpreter::executeCall(JSC::ExecState*, JSC::JSObject*, JSC::CallType, JSC::CallData const... + 408 (JITCodeInlines.h:38)
24  JavaScriptCore                  0x00000001b346fa54 JSC::boundThisNoArgsFunctionCall(JSC::ExecState*) + 460 (JSBoundFunction.cpp:56)
25  JavaScriptCore                  0x00000001b2c9c960 vmEntryToNative + 256
26  JavaScriptCore                  0x00000001b31faef4 JSC::Interpreter::executeCall(JSC::ExecState*, JSC::JSObject*, JSC::CallType, JSC::CallData const... + 488 (Interpreter.cpp:906)
27  JavaScriptCore                  0x00000001b33e5b28 JSC::profiledCall(JSC::ExecState*, JSC::ProfilingReason, JSC::JSValue, JSC::CallType, JSC::CallDa... + 184 (CallData.cpp:59)
28  JavaScriptCore                  0x00000001b2cf63cc JSObjectCallAsFunction + 376 (JSObjectRef.cpp:740)
29  *App Name*              0x0000000100b6da0c facebook::jsc::JSCRuntime::call(facebook::jsi::Function const&, facebook::jsi::Value const&, facebook::jsi::Value const*, unsigned long) + 172 (JSCRuntime.cpp:1206)
30  *App Name*              0x0000000100b76070 facebook::jsi::Value facebook::jsi::Function::call<std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> > const&, std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<c... + 244 (jsi-inl.h:223)
31  *App Name*              0x0000000100b75ed0 std::__1::__function::__func<facebook::react::JSIExecutor::callFunction(std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> > const&, std::__1::basic_string<char, st... + 96 (JSIExecutor.cpp:215)
32  *App Name*              0x0000000100aafc44 void std::__1::__invoke_void_return_wrapper<void>::__call<void (*&)(std::__1::function<void ()> const&, std::__1::function<std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::alloca... + 72 (type_traits:4425)
33  *App Name*              0x0000000100b73e90 facebook::react::JSIExecutor::callFunction(std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> > const&, std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, st... + 356 (functional:1860)
34  *App Name*              0x0000000100b6a0e0 std::__1::__function::__func<facebook::react::NativeToJsBridge::runOnExecutorQueue(std::__1::function<void (facebook::react::JSExecutor*)>)::$_7, std::__1::allocator<facebook::react::NativeToJsBrid... + 60 (functional:1860)
35  *App Name*              0x0000000100ad1658 facebook::react::tryAndReturnError(std::__1::function<void ()> const&) + 40 (functional:1860)
36  *App Name*              0x0000000100adf1fc facebook::react::RCTMessageThread::tryFunc(std::__1::function<void ()> const&) + 24 (RCTMessageThread.mm:59)
37  CoreFoundation                  0x00000001a3ce8834 __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_BLOCK__ + 20 (CFRunLoop.c:1774)
38  CoreFoundation                  0x00000001a3ce7fd4 __CFRunLoopDoBlocks + 264 (CFRunLoop.c:1815)
39  CoreFoundation                  0x00000001a3ce370c __CFRunLoopRun + 2312 (CFRunLoop.c:3124)
40  CoreFoundation                  0x00000001a3ce2adc CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 464 (CFRunLoop.c:3192)
41  *App Name*              0x0000000100ac72c0 +[RCTCxxBridge runRunLoop] + 264 (RCTCxxBridge.mm:268)
42  Foundation                      0x00000001a415309c __NSThread__start__ + 848 (NSThread.m:724)
43  libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00000001a3a85d8c _pthread_start + 156 (pthread.c:896)
44  libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00000001a3a8976c thread_start + 8

Thread 3 name:
Thread 3:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00000001a3b63b5c madvise + 8
1   JavaScriptCore                  0x00000001b2b08e84 bmalloc::BulkDecommit::process(std::__1::vector<std::__1::pair<char*, unsigned long>, std::__1::a... + 108 (VMAllocate.h:203)
2   JavaScriptCore                  0x00000001b2b08804 bmalloc::Scavenger::scavenge() + 412 (BulkDecommit.h:51)
3   JavaScriptCore                  0x00000001b2b08e08 bmalloc::Scavenger::threadRunLoop() + 372 (Scavenger.cpp:489)
4   JavaScriptCore                  0x00000001b2b08a44 bmalloc::Scavenger::threadEntryPoint(bmalloc::Scavenger*) + 12 (Scavenger.cpp:384)
5   JavaScriptCore                  0x00000001b2b09d50 void* std::__1::__thread_proxy<std::__1::tuple<std::__1::unique_ptr<std::__1::__thread_struct, st... + 40 (type_traits:4361)
6   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00000001a3a85d8c _pthread_start + 156 (pthread.c:896)
7   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00000001a3a8976c thread_start + 8

Thread 4 name:
Thread 4:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00000001a3b40634 mach_msg_trap + 8
1   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00000001a3b3faa0 mach_msg + 72 (mach_msg.c:103)
2   CoreFoundation                  0x00000001a3ce8288 __CFRunLoopServiceMachPort + 216 (CFRunLoop.c:2575)
3   CoreFoundation                  0x00000001a3ce33a8 __CFRunLoopRun + 1444 (CFRunLoop.c:2931)
4   CoreFoundation                  0x00000001a3ce2adc CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 464 (CFRunLoop.c:3192)
5   AVFAudio                        0x00000001b08c5c1c GenericRunLoopThread::Entry(void*) + 156 (GenericRunLoopThread.h:91)
6   AVFAudio                        0x00000001b0916d60 CAPThread::Entry(CAPThread*) + 204 (CAPThread.cpp:286)
7   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00000001a3a85d8c _pthread_start + 156 (pthread.c:896)
8   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00000001a3a8976c thread_start + 8

Thread 5 name:
Thread 5:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00000001a3b40634 mach_msg_trap + 8
1   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00000001a3b3faa0 mach_msg + 72 (mach_msg.c:103)
2   CoreFoundation                  0x00000001a3ce8288 __CFRunLoopServiceMachPort + 216 (CFRunLoop.c:2575)
3   CoreFoundation                  0x00000001a3ce33a8 __CFRunLoopRun + 1444 (CFRunLoop.c:2931)
4   CoreFoundation                  0x00000001a3ce2adc CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 464 (CFRunLoop.c:3192)
5   CFNetwork                       0x00000001a6fac4e8 -[__CoreSchedulingSetRunnable runForever] + 192 (CoreSchedulingSet.mm:1372)
6   Foundation                      0x00000001a415309c __NSThread__start__ + 848 (NSThread.m:724)
7   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00000001a3a85d8c _pthread_start + 156 (pthread.c:896)
8   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00000001a3a8976c thread_start + 8

Thread 6:
0   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00000001a3a89758 start_wqthread + 0

Thread 7:
0   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00000001a3a89758 start_wqthread + 0

Thread 8 name:
Thread 8:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00000001a3b61c94 __psynch_cvwait + 8
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00000001a3a7ecf8 _pthread_cond_wait$VARIANT$mp + 680 (pthread_cond.c:591)
2   JavaScriptCore                  0x00000001b2ac9afc WTF::ThreadCondition::timedWait(WTF::Mutex&, WTF::WallTime) + 144 (ThreadingPOSIX.cpp:541)
3   JavaScriptCore                  0x00000001b2aaf9a8 WTF::ParkingLot::parkConditionallyImpl(void const*, WTF::ScopedLambda<bool ()> const&, WTF::Scope... + 2040 (ParkingLot.cpp:596)
4   JavaScriptCore                  0x00000001b2a88264 bool WTF::Condition::waitUntil<WTF::Lock>(WTF::Lock&, WTF::TimeWithDynamicClockType const&) + 184 (ParkingLot.h:80)
5   JavaScriptCore                  0x00000001b2a885ec WTF::Detail::CallableWrapper<WTF::AutomaticThread::start(WTF::AbstractLocker const&)::$_0, void>:... + 216 (Condition.h:115)
6   JavaScriptCore                  0x00000001b2ac7734 WTF::Thread::entryPoint(WTF::Thread::NewThreadContext*) + 256 (Function.h:79)
7   JavaScriptCore                  0x00000001b2ac92a4 WTF::wtfThreadEntryPoint(void*) + 12 (ThreadingPOSIX.cpp:200)
8   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00000001a3a85d8c _pthread_start + 156 (pthread.c:896)
9   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00000001a3a8976c thread_start + 8

Thread 9 name:
Thread 9:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00000001a3b61c94 __psynch_cvwait + 8
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00000001a3a7ecf8 _pthread_cond_wait$VARIANT$mp + 680 (pthread_cond.c:591)
2   JavaScriptCore                  0x00000001b2ac9afc WTF::ThreadCondition::timedWait(WTF::Mutex&, WTF::WallTime) + 144 (ThreadingPOSIX.cpp:541)
3   JavaScriptCore                  0x00000001b2aaf9a8 WTF::ParkingLot::parkConditionallyImpl(void const*, WTF::ScopedLambda<bool ()> const&, WTF::Scope... + 2040 (ParkingLot.cpp:596)
4   JavaScriptCore                  0x00000001b2a88264 bool WTF::Condition::waitUntil<WTF::Lock>(WTF::Lock&, WTF::TimeWithDynamicClockType const&) + 184 (ParkingLot.h:80)
5   JavaScriptCore                  0x00000001b2a885ec WTF::Detail::CallableWrapper<WTF::AutomaticThread::start(WTF::AbstractLocker const&)::$_0, void>:... + 216 (Condition.h:115)
6   JavaScriptCore                  0x00000001b2ac7734 WTF::Thread::entryPoint(WTF::Thread::NewThreadContext*) + 256 (Function.h:79)
7   JavaScriptCore                  0x00000001b2ac92a4 WTF::wtfThreadEntryPoint(void*) + 12 (ThreadingPOSIX.cpp:200)
8   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00000001a3a85d8c _pthread_start + 156 (pthread.c:896)
9   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00000001a3a8976c thread_start + 8

Thread 10 name:
Thread 10 Crashed:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00000001a3b61ec4 __pthread_kill + 8
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00000001a3a7d1d8 pthread_kill$VARIANT$mp + 136 (pthread.c:1458)
2   libsystem_c.dylib               0x00000001a39d1844 abort + 100 (abort.c:110)
3   libc++abi.dylib                 0x00000001a3b2a7d4 abort_message + 128 (abort_message.cpp:76)
4   libc++abi.dylib                 0x00000001a3b2a9c4 demangling_terminate_handler() + 296 (cxa_default_handlers.cpp:66)
5   libobjc.A.dylib                 0x00000001a3a92258 _objc_terminate() + 124 (objc-exception.mm:701)
6   libc++abi.dylib                 0x00000001a3b37304 std::__terminate(void (*)()) + 16 (cxa_handlers.cpp:59)
7   libc++abi.dylib                 0x00000001a3b3729c std::terminate() + 44 (cxa_handlers.cpp:87)
8   libdispatch.dylib               0x00000001a3a37198 _dispatch_client_callout + 36 (object.m:498)
9   libdispatch.dylib               0x00000001a39e3404 _dispatch_lane_serial_drain$VARIANT$mp + 608 (inline_internal.h:2484)
10  libdispatch.dylib               0x00000001a39e3df8 _dispatch_lane_invoke$VARIANT$mp + 420 (queue.c:3863)
11  libdispatch.dylib               0x00000001a39ed314 _dispatch_workloop_worker_thread + 588 (queue.c:6445)
12  libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00000001a3a86b88 _pthread_wqthread + 276 (pthread.c:2351)
13  libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00000001a3a89760 start_wqthread + 8

Thread 11 name:
Thread 11:
0   libobjc.A.dylib                 0x00000001a3aac170 objc_release + 64 (objc-object.h:696)
1   libobjc.A.dylib                 0x00000001a3aad6d0 AutoreleasePoolPage::releaseUntil(objc_object**) + 180 (NSObject.mm:777)
2   libobjc.A.dylib                 0x00000001a3aad5c8 objc_autoreleasePoolPop + 224 (NSObject.mm:1037)
3   libdispatch.dylib               0x00000001a3a36610 _dispatch_call_block_and_release + 24 (init.c:1408)
4   libdispatch.dylib               0x00000001a3a37184 _dispatch_client_callout + 16 (object.m:495)
5   libdispatch.dylib               0x00000001a39e3404 _dispatch_lane_serial_drain$VARIANT$mp + 608 (inline_internal.h:2484)
6   libdispatch.dylib               0x00000001a39e3e28 _dispatch_lane_invoke$VARIANT$mp + 468 (queue.c:3863)
7   libdispatch.dylib               0x00000001a39ed314 _dispatch_workloop_worker_thread + 588 (queue.c:6445)
8   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00000001a3a86b88 _pthread_wqthread + 276 (pthread.c:2351)
9   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00000001a3a89760 start_wqthread + 8

Thread 12:
0   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00000001a3a89758 start_wqthread + 0

Thread 13:
0   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00000001a3a89758 start_wqthread + 0

Thread 10 crashed with ARM Thread State (64-bit):
    x0: 0x0000000000000000   x1: 0x0000000000000000   x2: 0x0000000000000000   x3: 0x0000000000000000
    x4: 0x00000001a3b3a5d8   x5: 0x000000016f9b2450   x6: 0x000000000000006e   x7: 0x000000000000005f
    x8: 0x000000016f9b3000   x9: 0x94ad59bad9f57794  x10: 0x00000001a3a7d150  x11: 0x000000000000000b
   x12: 0x00000001dbde2080  x13: 0x0000000000000001  x14: 0x0000000000000010  x15: 0x0000000000000001
   x16: 0x0000000000000148  x17: 0x0000000000000000  x18: 0x0000000000000000  x19: 0x0000000000000006
   x20: 0x000000000000ab1f  x21: 0x000000016f9b2450  x22: 0x000000016f9b30e0  x23: 0x0000000000000000
   x24: 0x0000000000000000  x25: 0x00000002860ebb80  x26: 0x000000028103de00  x27: 0x0000000000000000
   x28: 0x0000000000000000   fp: 0x000000016f9b23b0   lr: 0x00000001a3a7d1d8
    sp: 0x000000016f9b2390   pc: 0x00000001a3b61ec4 cpsr: 0x40000000
   esr: 0x56000080  Address size fault
```

Comment: we've had a lot of success with this package https://www.bugsnag.com